# css class no effect in jquery append statement

Tags: jquery, css

I'm try to apply a css class in jquery append statement

another css file

```
#comments {
    border:none;
}
#comments div {
    border:1px #FFFFFF solid;
}
#comments div div {
    border:1px #FF0000 dotted;
}
.test {
    border:1px #FF0000 solid;
}
```

a javascript file, #comment is a div

```
success: function (data) {

        $("#comments").html("");
          $.each(data,function (node_index,node_value) {

            var created = timeConverter(node_value.created);

            $("#comments").append($("<div></div>",{"class": "ui-body ui-body-c comments_div","html":node_value.name + "@" + created +"<br><div>" + node_value.subject + "</div>"+ "<br><div class=test>" + node_value.comment_body_value + "</div>"}));

          });
          $("#comments").collapsibleset();

        }
```

But there is no effect for the class .test, anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Make a fiddle it will be easier to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem with CSS order of precedence([specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Specificity)) where the rule `#comments div` overrides the rule `.test`

Try

```
#comments div.test {
    border:1px #FF0000 solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#comments div` is overriding `.test`.

Try this:

```
.test {
    border:1px #FF0000 solid !important;
}
```